# preg_match to remove {$ ... }

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking for a regex to preg_replace in strings between curly brackets followed by $ symbol in this way:

```
{$string} //match
{$123string} //match
{string} //no match
{$string123} //match
[$string] //no match
```

Comment: I am rather confused about what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have `$string` **{$Emergento}**.

If you want to replace the entire string, then use:

```
preg_replace('/({\\$.*?})/', $sub, $string);
```

If you want to replace **$Emergento**, then use:

```
preg_replace('/{(\\$.*?)}/', $sub, $string);
```

and if you want to replace just **Emergento**, then use:

```
preg_replace('/{\\$(.*?)}/', $sub, $string);
```

Comment: Question title says they want it all removed, I think.

Comment: @AlexLunix - There is no "all", so nobody is sure what exactly OP wants, so just in case...

Answer (score 6):

```
preg_replace('/{\\$(.+)}/', $replacement, $subject);
```

This is very basic RegExp, **[please do read](http://www.regular-expressions.info)**.